# Is cakephp-3 removing expired sessions from my database?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

my sessions database table is filling up (size is approaching 1GB after ~2 month). There are lots of sessions with a past exipation date. I can write a cron-job to remove them regularly, but is this the recommended way to go? Or has cakephp a build in function to clean up expired sessions, that is not properly configured or disabled in my app?

My session configuration:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_path' => '/',
        'session.cookie_domain' => 'something.local'
    ],
    'timeout' => 4320 // 3 days
],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP's database session handler uses the standardized PHP session handler API, ie it implements the `SessionHandlerInterface` and is being hooked up via `session_set_save_handler()`.

The save handler implements the `gc()` method that removes expired sessions, that is rows where the condition `expires < time()` applies. It is being invoked internally by PHP when a session starts, depending on the `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_probability` settings.

If your expired sessions aren't removed frequently enough, try changing PHP's garbage collection settings and/or the session timeout settings (see the `timeout` option) in case applicable.

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Session Extensions > Sessions > SessionHandler > gc()](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php)**
- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Session Extensions > Sessions >  Installing/Configuring > ini.session.gc-divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor)**
- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Session Extensions > Sessions >  Installing/Configuring > ini.session.gc-probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)**
- **[Cookbook > Sessions > Session Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Sessions > Setting ini directives](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives)**

Comment: In my case it was the setting of `session.gc_probability` (which was set to 0 on the production server).